# How to package using mvn -f with the pom.xml being present two folders up in folder tree?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file

I am writing a script on Windows platform in which I need to package the *Maven* project. Now the issue is that I need to use this command right and the `pom.xml` is in the folder two levels up, or `cd ..`, `cd ..`.

What modification is needed for this command line not working as expected?

```
mvn -f \.\.\ package -DskipTests
```

The current directory is:

```
C:\Users\mike\Documents\mavenapp\fold1\fold2
```

I need to execute `mvn` past two folders, i.e. in directory `mavenapp`.

I don´t want to do it this way because this would be a hard-coded solution:

```
mvn -f C:\Users\mike\Documents\mavenapp package -DskipTests
```

Comment: I suggest to read first the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) which every programmer writing code on Windows for Windows programs or script should have read at least once. The folder path specification ``\.\.\`` references the __root__ directory of __current drive__ (first backslash), next that directory once again with ``.\`` and next that directory once again with one more ``.\`` which is not want you want.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `call /?` and read the output help explaining how to reference batch file arguments. The argument 0 is always the batch file itself. So if the batch file is stored in `%UserProfile%\Documents\mavenapp\fold1\fold2` and you want to use in the command line the path of the folder two levels up, you best use `mvn -f "%~dp0..\..\" package -DskipTest` to reference this folder. I recommend to write not just `mvn`, but at least `mvn` with file extension. (`.exe` or `.com` or `.cmd` or `.bat`, I don't know it.)

Comment: Please note that the batch file path referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with the Windows directory separator ``\`` and for that reason the concatenation of `%~dp0` with a file or folder name or a wildcard pattern should be always done __without__ an additional backslash for a 100% valid argument string with batch file path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try `mvn ../../../pom.xml package` ?

Comment: That does not work if the current directory on execution is different to the directory containing the batch file and all other files and folders. Windows Explorer sets the current directory of `cmd.exe` started to process the batch file to the batch file directory by default. But the current directory can be different on using `Run as administrator` or the batch file is stored on a network resource and the network resource is accessed using UNC path. And it is of course possible to run a batch file from within a command prompt window with full qualified file name from within any directory.

Comment: In other words this code using Linux/Mac directory separator `/` instead of Windows directory separator ``\`` works only by chance and not by design as it expects that the process starting `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file sets the current working directory for the command process `cmd.exe` to the directory of the batch file. There are thousands of directories on a Windows machine which could be the current working directory on starting `cmd.exe` to process the batch file, but only one directory for which this code works.

Comment: There is no right way of this with the command line by loading a strange path. The right way should be to add a pom file where you need to run mvn. But for a fast solution i think that using ../ is a good choice

Comment: What I wanted to let you know is that `../` is not really correct on Windows as the directory separator is ``\`` and for that reason ``..\`` should be used to reference the file `pom.xml` with a relative path. Yes, `../` works also because of automatic replacement (correction) of all `/` by ``\`` by Windows file management as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). But it is nevertheless better to use on Windows ``\`` as directory separator and not `/`.

Comment: The question is not detailed enough regarding to directory structure and which directory is the current directory on execution of the batch file and where are all the files required by `mvn` for a successful processing them. I think that you have one `../` (or better ``..\``) too much used in your answer as far as I understood the task description in question. I think also that referencing the file `pom.xml` with a path relative to batch file folder would be better than referencing the file `pom.xml` with a path relative to current directory. However, the questioner accepted your answer.